# Criando uma lista de elementos percorrendo um array associativo em EcmaScript

Tags: javascript, html5, ecmascript-6

Eu estou tentando criar uma parte do menu superior com EcmaScript em vez de html puro, porém não estou entendendo o que falta para acrescentar o elemento.

Código **HTML**

```
  <div class="rd-navbar-cell rd-navbar-nav-wrap" id="list">

       <ul class="rd-navbar-nav rd-navbar-nav-default">
             <!-- Queria que os elementos que estão no Array vão parar aqui -->
      </ul>

 </div>
```

Código **EcmaScript:**

```
var listElement = document.querySelector("#list ul")
var listsElement = ['Home',
                    'Cursos',
                    'Promoções',
                    'Eventos',
                    'Blog',
                    'Quem-somos',
                    'Soluções Corporativas',
                    'Parceiros' 
                    ]
var x = listsElement.map(function(item){

    return item;

})

listElement.createElement('li')
listElement.appendChild(x)
```

Sinto que está faltando alguma coisa para acrescentar ou está errado... Alguém poderia me explicar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aluns erros de lógica:

- tens de usar o `createElement` uma vez para cada `li``
- o `createElement` é um método de `document`
- para adicionar conteudo podes usar o `textContent`
- usa `.forEach` o `.map` não é possível inserir em bruto

Exemplo:

```js
var listElement = document.querySelector("#list ul")
var listsElement = ['Home',
  'Cursos',
  'Promoções',
  'Eventos',
  'Blog',
  'Quem-somos',
  'Soluções Corporativas',
  'Parceiros'
]
listsElement.forEach(function(tipo) {
  const li = document.createElement('li')
  li.textContent = tipo;
  listElement.appendChild(li)
});
```

```html
<div class="rd-navbar-cell rd-navbar-nav-wrap" id="list">

  <ul class="rd-navbar-nav rd-navbar-nav-default">
    <!-- Queria que os elementos que estão no Array vão parar aqui -->
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Opa @Sergio obrigado pela resposta, eu pensava que `.map` tinha o mesmo efeito de um `foreach.`

Comment: @RodrigoPires mais ou menos... semânticamente são diferentes, o `.map` é para criar uma nova array. Mas na prática ambas percorrem a array.